# Make a function stop working when a button is clicked(javascrpt)

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

I want to make a `function` stop working when a button is clicked in Javascript.

I try to use the `if` statement to check if the button is clicked or not. Also, I have tried to make the function stop working when a certain condition met inside another function.

However, it still doesn't work anymore.

Does anyone know how to make it works and why the `onclick == true` doesn't work anymore?

```js
let textarea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0]
let message = document.getElementById('message')

function clicks() {
  console.log('hi')
  //I want to make the appear function stop working when this function is executing.
}

function appear() {
  //this is not working
  if (document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick == true) {
    message.style.display = 'none'
    console.log('it works')
  } else {
    message.style.display = 'revert'
    textarea.value = textarea.value.trimStart();
  }
};
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<div id="message">.....</div>
<button onclick="clicks()">split(20px)</button>
```

Comment: `.onclick == true` makes no sense. The onclick property holds the reference to the function object you assigned as the click handler (and as such, this condition will always evaluate to true.) This has nothing to do with whether the button was actually clicked. Just toggle the value of a boolean flag from within your handler function, then you can check on that flag on the next click.

Comment: How is `appear` called? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: Along w CBroe's comment, a hidden field that holds the value true or false could do the trick.

Comment: @CBroe, I am not pretty sure how to do it. For example, if I do the handler function, will it become true when i clicked it for the first time and become false when i clicked it for the second time....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onclick` is an event, which fired, when `click` event occurred. As a result, `onclick` doesn`t store state. You need to create variable, visible for `clicks` and `appear` functions, and use it to identify the flag to stop execution of function `appear`.

```js
    let textarea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
    let message = document.getElementById("message");
    let stopButtonClicked = false;

    function clicks() {
        console.log("hi");
        stopButtonClicked = true;
    }

    function appear() {
        if (stopButtonClicked) {
            message.style.display = "none";
            console.log("it works");
        } else {
            message.style.display = "revert";
            textarea.value = textarea.value.trimStart();
        }
    }
```

Comment: only when the stopButtonClicked is true, it will console. Is it correct?

Comment: @Shawn this code will be executed `message.style.display = "none"; console.log("it works");`

Comment: I mean the `message.style.display = "none"; console.log("it works")` will only works when the stopButtonClicked. Is it correct?

Comment: @Shawn Yes, but only when `appear` function called. You should really try this code by yourself. Make some work, please.

Comment: I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply semaphore logic, like:

```
let beingClicked = false;
function clicks() {
  
  beingClicked = true;
  console.log('hi');
  //I want to make the appear function stop working when this function is executing.
  beingClicked = false;
}

function appear() {
  //this is not working
  if (beingClicked) {
    message.style.display = 'none'
    console.log('it works')
  } else {
    message.style.display = 'revert'
    textarea.value = textarea.value.trimStart();
  }
};
```

Note that at the start of the `function`, we set the semaphore (`beingClicked`) to red (which is `true` in this case) and at the end of the `function` we set it to `false`.

It is important to note that there are two further problems to consider:

## 1

You may need to reuse this logic for other buttons. If so, then you could consider the following:

```
function ButtonSemaphore(button) {
    let semaphore = false;
    let events = [];
    button.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
        semaphore = true;
        for (let event of events) event(evt);
        semaphore = false;
    });
    function isRed() {
        return semaphore;
    }
    function isGreen() {
        return !semaphore;
    }
    function addEvent(callback) {
        events.push(callback);
    }
}
```

You can instantiate this by calling it as `let myButtonSemaphore = new ButtonSemaphore(button)`, where `button` is a valid button. Whenever you want to add an event to it, just call `myButtonSemaphore.addEvent(function(evt) {/* Some code */})`. Note that the event array is processed and the semaphore is set properly before all events and after all events.

## 2

You may need to reuse this, so it is recommended to create a .js file of its own, so your code will exist exactly once and will be importable whenever needed.

Comment: @Arpad, I feel a bit confused that why you set the  `beingClicked` to true at the beginging and set it to `false` at the end. Could you explain it to me? Thanks so much for answering my question.

Comment: @Shawn because if between setting it to true and setting it to false you call `appear`, then while `appear` is being executed, then, at that stage `beingClicked` is `true`. If you call `appear` before or after the click, then `beingClicked` is false. Since we want a different behavior of `appear` in these two scenarios, it is fitting to set `beingClicked` to true when it is being clicked and to false when it's no longer being clicked.

Comment: @Shawn think about `beingClicked` as a semaphore, your program a car, the click event as a crossroad. When the car reaches the crossroad, it has to stop because the semaphore is red and once all the cars (events) that it's waiting for have passed, the semaphore turns green and the passage can be continued.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let textarea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0]
let message = document.getElementById('message')

function clicks() {
  console.log('hi')
  //I want to make the appear function stop working when this function is executing.
}

function appear() {
  //this is not working
  if (document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick == true) {
    message.style.display = 'none'
    console.log('it works')
  } else {
    message.style.display = 'revert'
    textarea.value = textarea.value.trimStart();
  }
};
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<div id="message">.....</div>
<button onclick="clicks()">split(20px)</button>
```